# How to save user data

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've this initState in the main page for checking auth:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((fire) {
      if (fire != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isAuth = true;
          print('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^6');

          print(_isAuth);
          print('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^6');
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

At sign in the user data saved, But if the user already authentic all the data(email, id etc..) lost.

Sign in:

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> signIn() async {
        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
            idWhat is the best way to keep the information?
Token: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
        final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        print(user.displayName);
        _authUser = User(id: user.uid, userEmail: user.email);
        notifyListeners();

        return user;
      }
```

What is the best way to save the data?

Comment: save your data in shared preferences

Comment: You can try using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) to save the data